# Access object using dynamic object name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an object with some data inside. The first level of data are 2 arrays (body, cause). Each body and cause array have arrays inside of them (date, year).

```
totals:[{body:[
            {date:[54,9,3,17]},
            {year:[437,61,31,140]}]},
        {cause:[
            {date:[54,9,3,17]},
            {year:[437,61,31,140]}]
        }]
```

What I would like to do is access the body/cause array dynamically based on something the user has changed.

This is how I am accessing them now.

```
totals[isCause].body[isYear].date[filterNumber]);
```

My issues is body and date are hard coded in there, and I would like to have access to either body/cause date/year. I can't seem to find what these property names are stored as. I tried to set up a var and do something like this

```
var bodyCause = "body";
```

Then I tried to pass it back into my retriever statement.

```
totals[isCause].bodyCause[isYear].date[filterNumber]);
```

But that fails. So I'm just trying to figure out what that property name is stored as and if I can dynamically set it when I need to retrieve information.

Comment: You already know how to access a property dynamically: `totals[isCause]`.

Comment: `totals[isCause][bodyCause][isYear].date[filterNumber]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt was almost correct. You can easyly use `var bodyCause = "body";` and access the content dynamically. Instead of this

```
totals[isCause].bodyCause[isYear].date[filterNumber]);
```

you should use this

```
totals[isCause][bodyCause][isYear].date[filterNumber]);
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that information!